# How can I prevent a select field from reverting to default on form errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<%= f.select :foo , options_for_select([['Foo', true], ['Bar', false]],  :class => 'btn btn-default') %>
```

This works, but the problem I'm having is if the user selects `Bar` and submits the form, and there are errors that cause the page to render again, the selection goes back to `Foo`, which users can easily miss and cause them to submit the form with the wrong data.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put params[:foo] after collection

```
 <%= f.select :foo , options_for_select([['Foo', true], ['Bar', false]], params[:object][:foo]), :class => 'btn btn-default'%>
```

Comment: Pasting it as is gives me incorrect number of arguments.  I tried moving it outside of the `options_for_select`, but got `undefined method 'merge' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007f72e9520630>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `form_for`, the form is wrapping your object instance. That means, that if your form is re-rendered then the select should be set to the same thing as is in the object instance. So my suspicion is that your object is actually not properly set. You can check but putting a breakpoint in your view code just before the select. Then, in the debugger, try `f.object.foo` to see what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%= f.select :foo , options_for_select([['Foo', true], ['Bar', false]],  :class => 'btn btn-default') %>
```

With

```
<%= f.select :foo , options_for_select([['Foo', true], ['Bar', false]], f.object.foo),  {}, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Pass the selected value as 2nd argument to `options_for_select` method. Refer to **[options_for_select method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)** docs.

Also, html_options should be the 4th argument passed to `f.select`. So, changed `:class => 'btn btn-default'` to `{}, :class => 'btn btn-default'` this way the 3rd argument is passed as empty hash and `:class` is passed as 4th.

Comment: @Lunyx Did my answer resolve your issue? Let me know what the result is, if any issue we can discuss it.